# Is $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^2}$ Fréchet differentiable as a function on the Sobolev Space $H^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces

Consider the function $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^2}:H^1(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ and a point $0\neq f\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L^2}$ Fréchet differentiable w.r.t. to the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{H^1}$? I.e. is there a bounded linear operator $A:H^1(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$, s.t.

\begin{equation}
     \lim_{\Vert g\Vert_{H^1}\to 0} \frac{\left\lvert  \Vert f+g\Vert_{L^2} - \Vert f\Vert_{L^2} - Ag\right\rvert}{\Vert g\Vert_{H^1}} = 0?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. We may show (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Example_in_infinite_dimensions) for example) that, for a Hilbert space $H$, the derivative of the norm $\|\cdot\|$ at $f \in H$ is given by
$$A(f)(g) = \left\langle g, \frac{f}{\|f\|}\right\rangle.$$

This implies that, in the $L^2$ case,
\begin{equation}
     \lim_{\Vert g\Vert_{L^2}\to 0} \frac{\left\lvert  \Vert f+g\Vert_{L^2} - \Vert f\Vert_{L^2} - A(f)(g)\right\rvert}{\Vert g\Vert_{L^2}} = 0.
\end{equation}
As $\|g\|_{L^2} \le \|g\|_{H^1}$, we have
$$\frac{\left\lvert  \Vert f+g\Vert_{L^2} - \Vert f\Vert_{L^2} - A(f)(g)\right\rvert}{\Vert g\Vert_{H^1}} \le \frac{\left\lvert  \Vert f+g\Vert_{L^2} - \Vert f\Vert_{L^2} - A(f)(g)\right\rvert}{\Vert g\Vert_{L^2}}$$
and we conclude the desired result.

Comment: But what about the linear operator $A$? The $A$ you take is bounded w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm, but I don't see how it is bounded w.r.t. the $H^1$-norm.

Comment: If it is bounded wrt the $L^2$ norm, it is in particular bounded for the $H^1$ norm:
$$|A(f)(g)| \le C \|g\|_{L^2} \le C\|g\|_{H^1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the answer!

Comment: You are very welcome!